# dynamic_cast with virtual inheritance triggers access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, dynamic-cast, virtual-inheritance

I have specific class hierarchy which crashes at runtime.(Visual Studio 2017)

```
struct A{};
struct B
{
    auto f()
    {
        dynamic_cast<A *>(this);//triggers: Access violation
    }

    virtual ~B() = default;
};

struct C :virtual B, A//remove "virtual" to fix
{
    C()
    {
        f();
    }
    int a;//remove to fix
};
struct D :virtual C{};//remove "virtual" to fix

int main() 
{
    D d;
}
```

Question is:
Is this problem of code or rather compiler bug?

I tried a lots of variations, but none of them was satisfying, since this code looks correct for me.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` doesn't always work as expected when called form a constructor, much like `virtual` functions don't always do what you expect.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It depends what *you* expect! In a constructor of a non virtual base subobject with no virtual base, virtual functions and `dynamic_cast` and everything behave exactly like in a complete class of that type being constructed, even with abstract class that just completed with invalid definition of the pure virtual function. In practice in all implementations, everything matches the behavior of the complete class: layout, the value of all vptr so the formalization of expectations is easy. This isn't true if you have virtual bases as the base object isn't like a complete object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In which specific cases will `dynamic_cast` be ill behaved when used on a base class subject under construction where virtual inheritance is involved? (Of couse `dynamic_cast<T>(this)` won't be used with a premature `this`.)

Comment: Please post the offsets of subobjects in `C` vs `D`

Comment: "`int a;//remove to fix`" I guess `C::a` makes `D` grow as it prevents `C` from being primary in complete `D` which changes... something. Please post the overhead of `D` with and without `C::a`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The only virtual functions you can never call from a constructor are direct destructor call (`this->~T();`) and deleting destructor (`delete this;`)

Comment: @Acorn "_This question already has an answer here_" Really? Where?

Comment: It seems that I must recognize polymorphism as inaccessible in constructors. It's a pity there are no warnings and it's easy to ignore that.

Comment: @Pjoter Polymorphism works fine in constructors!